# Find an element with Selenium Webdriver which fulfils multiple By-criteria

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using v2.52 of Selenium and the WebDriver with C#. What I am trying to achieve should be fairly simple, but I am unable to find the solution for: I'd like to find an element by multiple `By`-criteria.

Let's say, I have something like this:

```
<a href="#" class="foo">Click me!</a>
<a href="#" class="bar">Click me!</a>
<p class="foo">Click me!</p>
```

Ignore the fact, that I could use `By.CssSelector`, `By.CssSelector`, `By.XPath` and so on. I was assuming that it should be possible to do something like this:

```
driver.FindElement(By.TagName("a").ClassName("foo"))
// ...or something like this...
driver.FindElement(By.TagName("a"), By.ClassName("foo"))
```

`OpenQA.Selenium.Support.PageObjects.ByChained` does not do the trick, since it is searching hierarchical.

Is there a way to find element(s) which match multiple `By`-criteria?

Best regards,
   Carsten

Comment: and what is wrong with `XPath` and `CssSelector`?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with it. Okay, maybe XPath is a bit to static. I am just wondering if I can find elements the way I described it.

Comment: I guess there is no such way to find element by multiple filters. Anyway, `xpath` would be more flexible as there are a lot of `HTML` attributes that can be found only with `xpath` and `cssSelector`. Also note that class names, that contain spaces, can't be matched with  `By.ClassName("f o o")` method, but can be matched with `By.XPath('//*[@class="f o o"]')`...

Answer (score 0):

I imagine something like this may work for your case:

```
public IWebElement FindElementByMultipleCriteria(List<By> Criteria, IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> toFilter = null)
{
    // If we've reached the end of the criteria list, return the first element:
    if (Criteria.Count == 0 && toFilter != null) return toFilter.ElementAt(0);

    // Take the head of the criteria list
    By currentCriteria = Criteria[0];
    Criteria.RemoveAt(0);

    // If no list of elements found exists, we get all elements from the current criteria:
    if (toFilter == null)
    {
        toFilter = Driver.FindElements(currentCriteria);
    }
    // If a list does exist, we must filter out the ones that aren't found by the current criteria:
    else
    {
        List<IWebElement> newFilter = new List<IWebElement>();
        foreach(IWebElement e in Driver.FindElements(currentCriteria))
        {
            if (toFilter.Contains(e)) newFilter.Add(e);
        }
        toFilter = newFilter.AsReadOnly();
    }

    // Pass in the refined criteria and list of elements found.
    return FindElementByMultipleCriteria(Criteria, toFilter);
}

IWebElement example = FindElementByMultipleCriteria(new List<By>(){ By.TagName("a"), ClassName("foo") });
```

Essentially, you're taking the list of elements found by the first `By` passed in. You are then going through the remaining `By` criteria and removing elements from that initial list that are never found again.

This is horribly inefficient and I don't really understand why you would want to do this, but it exists.

Oh also, you'll need to add `using System.Linq;` in order to interact with the `IReadOnlyCollection`.

Comment: Indeed, this sounds like a horrible idea. ;) If there is no support out of the box, fine by me. I was wondering if there is something available, but obviously not.

Comment: I imagine it doesn't exist because you could give it a horrendous list of criteria like `[By.TagName("a"), By.TagName("input"), By.TagName("h1")]` and just brick your program, haha

Answer (score 0):

Well I think you can try something like this, and let me know if it works:

```
    public IWebElement FindElementUsingNestedBy(By firstCriteria, By secondCriteria)
    {
        var allElements = Driver.FindElements(firstCriteria);
        foreach (var webElement in allElements)
        {
            try
            {
                var desiredObject = webElement.FindElement(secondCriteria);
                return desiredObject;
            }
            catch (NotFoundException ex)
            {

            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken, this is not what I am looking for. Your `secondCriteria` is searching for elements underneath (from the DOM's point of view) of those elements from `firstCriteria`. This functionality is already covered by `ByChained`. I want that all criteria are matching on an element.